# Is it possible to create a Voronoi RadialLine?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, procedural

I could make something similar to Swirl, but I want to make a line towards the center of each Voronoi!
Would it be possible for me to make it?
[image]

Current node configuration
[image]

I want the texture to look like this.
[image]

Comment: twirl or radial? it's not clear

Comment: Sorry.
I would like to be Radial like in the image
https://i.imgur.com/4sJZ7mK.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, working in Object Space. The *Position* output of the Voronoi node is the location of the feature point from which the attributes (distance, etc) of the local cell are measured. If you subtract it from the shading point, you get the vector from the feature point to the shading point .. a mini UV map for each cell, with its origin at the feature point.

[image]

If you Nornalize those coordinates, you get a measure of direction from the cell origin expressed as XY (all the points in the same direction from the cell origin will all have the same unit vector), so that can be used for radial effects. Here, the vector is used to look up into a *Noise* texture.

[image]

Edit: Working in 3D, and normalizing at every stage, effectively ensures all the points used in the direction calculations are projected onto the unit sphere, towards or away from its center:

[image]

..and so straight lines become arcs:

[image]

(but this will work only on a sphere, not on any curved surface, and, to work in Object Space, the origin of your sphere-object should be at its center)

Edit 2:

You can animate the effect by scaling the sphere onto which the feature-point is projected:

[image]

With this sort of result:

[image]

This is the simplest way. To get more specific effects, you may have to extract, say, the Normal Z to work with, which would be a bigger tree.

Comment: Thank you! That's pretty close to what I'm looking for!
But when we apply it to the sphere, the sides seem to stretch vertically.
I don't know what the solution is.
https://i.imgur.com/QHSP6Hp.png

Comment: It looks a little different from that picture...https://imgur.com/o5VN5il

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/CXS57Fq.mp4 I want to adjust the density, like in this video

Comment: @InamuraJIN I hope this is something like the effect you are looking for .. see edit, again.

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you!!!!!

Comment: @InamuraJIN   Great! ... if you'd be so good... could you mark the answer as accepted? It doesn't matter so much to me, but might, when others, newer to BSE, answer a question successfully.

Comment: I just learned of this feature! I was wondering if this feature was missing! Thank you!